# Entity Framework. "Локальная" автоинкрементация

Tags: sql, база-данных, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
public class Message
{
   [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
   public int UserId {get;set;}
   [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
   public int MessageId {get;set;}

   public string Body {get;set;}
}
```

Есть сущность Message. Можно ли как-то автоматически генерировать MessageId при добавлении в пределах одного UserId ?

А если нет, то приемлем ли такой вариант?

```
int userId = 1;
var message = new Message();
int lastMessageId = db.Messages.Where(m=>m.UserId==userId).OrderByDescending(m=>m.MessageId).First().MessageId;
message.MessageId = lastMessageId + 1;
db.Messages.Add(message);
```

Comment: в предложенном варианте куда более эффективным будет не выборка всех `id` их сортировка и взятие первого, а просто поиск максимального.

Comment: в частности предложенный вариант вызовет исключение, в случае, когда у пользователя нет связанных сообщений.

Comment: а в качестве альтернативного варианта заполнения поля можно предложить использовать триггер  на вставку данных в таблицу.
Хотя смысл хранения номеров сообщений для каждого пользователя в целом не очень понятен, ибо наверняка будет еще и какая то отметка времени.